# Subgroup Correspondence Theorem

Tags: group-theory

It is well known that if $N\trianglelefteq G$, then there is a 1-1 correspondence between subgropups of $G$ containing $N$ and subgroups of $G/N$ ([see this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29)).

The question I would like to ask may be trivial, but I didn't believe it myself quickly. I couldn't find it anywhere mentioned.

*If $H,K$ are subgroup of $G$ containing $N$, such that $H/N$ and $K/N$ are conjugate in $G/N$, does $H,K$ are conjugate in $G$? If this is not true for arbitrary normal subgroup, is it true when $N=Z(G)$, the center?*

I think answer is yes, but I would like from someone who has seen/ verified himself.

(Sorry, my purpose is to convince about this fact, whether true or false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: argue $(gN)(K/N)(gN)^{-1}$ corresponds to $gKg^{-1}$ in the lattice isomorphism theorem.